# How to update the query in TFS 2019 using C# VS2019

Tags: c#, tfs

https://blog.jongallant.com/2011/07/modify-tfs-query-with-c/

I found the blog which suggested to use StoredQuery which seems obsolete now.
I can't use project.StoredQueries and Update() method for StoredQuery.

So if I want to update the existing query text on tfs for some special condition, how to manage that? Thanks

Comment: I am able to get the query Id, name, text, but don't know how to post the query for modification

Comment: What error are you getting?  When you do a select query a mapping is created between the database and the c# results.  When you do an Update the mapping is used to save data back into the database.  So usually an Update fails if you are not using the same mapping as the select.  Update may fail if you are adding new items.  Insert needs to be used when saving new items.

Comment: Answer updated, please check if my update1's example can work for you. Just create a new console project and install necessary nuget packages, copy the code and run the code to test... If it works for you, please consider [marking it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that more members can benefit from correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [official sample link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/8f341f8e33adc8b1b4432b51ad2e10f0b7864739/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/QueriesSample.cs#L259) from `Github/Microsoft`.

```
        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public QueryHierarchyItem UpdateQuery()
        {
            Guid projectId = ClientSampleHelpers.FindAnyProject(this.Context).Id;
            Guid queryId = this.Context.GetValue<Guid>("$sampleQueryId");

            QueryHierarchyItem queryUpdate = new QueryHierarchyItem()
            {               
                Wiql = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [System.State] = 'Active' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
            };

            VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            try
            {
                QueryHierarchyItem query = workItemTrackingClient.UpdateQueryAsync(queryUpdate, projectId, queryId.ToString()).Result;

                Console.WriteLine("Query updated successfully");
                Console.WriteLine("Id:         {0}", query.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Name:       {0}", query.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Path:       {0}", query.Path);

                return query;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error updating query: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                return null;
            }                
        }
```

I think the `UpdateQueryAsync` method from `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` class is what you're looking for.

**Update1:**

Find another good sample from [ashamrai/TFRestApi](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/04.TFRestApiAppWorkItemQueries/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs). Since you only need to update the query, you can try code like this:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace UpdateQuery
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string TFUrl = "http://xxx:8080/tfs/xxx/"; // for devops azure 
        static readonly string UserAccount = "xxx";
        static readonly string UserPassword = "xxx";
        static readonly string UserPAT = "xxx";

        static WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WitClient;
        static BuildHttpClient BuildClient;
        static ProjectHttpClient ProjectClient;
        static GitHttpClient GitClient;
        static TfvcHttpClient TfvsClient;
        static TestManagementHttpClient TestManagementClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectWithDefaultCreds(TFUrl);
            string teamProject = "YourProjectName";
            string newQuery = @"SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project" +
                " and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'";
            EditQuery(teamProject,"My Queries/TestQuery", newQuery);
        }

       
        /// <summary>
        /// Update Existing Query
        /// </summary>
        static void EditQuery(string project, string queryPath, string newWiqlStr)
        {
            QueryHierarchyItem query = WitClient.GetQueryAsync(project, queryPath).Result;
            query.Wiql = newWiqlStr;
            query = WitClient.UpdateQueryAsync(query, project, queryPath).Result;
        }


        #region create new connections
        static void InitClients(VssConnection Connection)
        {
            WitClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            BuildClient = Connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
            ProjectClient = Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
            GitClient = Connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
            TfvsClient = Connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
            TestManagementClient = Connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
        }

        static void ConnectWithDefaultCreds(string ServiceURL)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssCredentials());
            InitClients(connection);
        }

        static void ConnectWithCustomCreds(string ServiceURL, string User, string Password)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential(User, Password)));
            InitClients(connection);
        }

        static void ConnectWithPAT(string ServiceURL, string PAT)
        {
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
            InitClients(connection);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

To install the packages you can check my content in project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client">
      <Version>5.2.7</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common.Contracts">
      <Version>16.170.0-preview</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client">
      <Version>16.170.0-preview</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow">
      <Version>4.5.24</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client">
      <Version>16.170.0-preview</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works on my side with VS2019 16.6 `.net fx 4.7.2` console app to update queries in TFS 2019.1.

Comment: You're welcome :) Feel free to let me know if you meet any trouble when trying the code.